# How to send two files from node?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have two html files.

1. mynewFile1.html
2. mynewFile2.html

How to send it to the Angular 4 client from nodejs?
How to get the files in angular 4 which is rendered from back end?

Comment: Do you have separate apps for frontend and backend?

Comment: You can just serve them statically. Why do you need to do that server-side?

Comment: yes, im using separate apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple actually. Just serve the files using static function of express.

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('Files'));//assuming you have the files within the folder Files
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Now, you can access your files via angular with the path of the server/filename. For example, if your nodejs api is hosted on `http://localhost:4200`. Access it in angular using:

```
 http://localhost:4200/mynewFile1.html
```